# Compilation Error MVC4 at the line "public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication"

Tags: c#, sql, c, asp.net-mvc-4

In the below code, it gives me an compilation error for the line "public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication"

Please, help me to solve this problem.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq; 
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace Simple_Calendar
{
// Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
// visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: What is the compilation error? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer:) Good Luck!

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application.
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 
Compiler Error Message: CS0260: Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'Simple_Calendar.MvcApplication'; another partial declaration of this type exists

Answer (score 0):

I think System.Web.HttpApplication dll has been corrupted  just add dll in your reference